# how to remove this warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationImpl is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationImpl;
public static Document newDocument( String pName ) {

    return DOMImplementationImpl.getDOMImplementation().createDocument(
        null,
        pName,
        DOMImplementationImpl.getDOMImplementation().createDocumentType( pName, null, null ) );

}
```

I have encounter with below warnings in netbeans

```
warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationImpl is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
return DOMImplementationImpl.getDOMImplementation().createDocument(


warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationImpl is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release DOMImplementationImpl.getDOMImplementation().createDocumentType( pName, null, null ) );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't refer to a concrete DOMImplementation. Instead, use:

```
DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
DOMImplementation implementation = registry.getDOMImplementation("XML 1.0");
DocumentType type = implementation.createDocumentType(pName, null, null);
Document document = implementation.createDocument(null, pname, type);
```

Alternatively, use a rather less factory-heavy XML API, like [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) :) (I've always found the Java W3C DOM API to be a complete pain to work with.)

Yet another alternative would be to use a concrete DOMImplementation, but make it an external one rather than relying on an implementation built into the JDK. This could still be [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/), just from a jar file.

Answer (score 3):

The way to remove the warning is to avoid using internal, undocumented classes and methods from Sun in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to remove the warning.  Rather remove the import statement, and use a different parser, which you initialize using its parser factory.